# Riemann-Liouville integral of $f$ is zero implies $f =0$ a.e

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

The Riemann-Liouville integral is defined by
$$
I^\alpha f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_a^x f(t)(x-t)^{\alpha-1} d t
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function and $a$ is an arbitrary but fixed base point. Take $a = 0$ and $\alpha = 1/2$ and $f \in L^1(0,\infty)$. Therefore we look at:
$$
I^x_{\frac{1}{2}} := \frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)} \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{x-t}} d t
$$
Suppose $I^x_{\frac{1}{2}} = 0$ for all $x$. Can we then conclude $f=0$ a.e.?

My approach so far has been to take the Fourier transform and use the convolution theorem. I cannot conclude because I do not know if $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Otherwise, I could conclude just by using the fact that the Fourier transform is an isometry between $L^2$ spaces. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681095/riemann-liouville-integral-of-f-is-zero-implies-f-0-a-e) for the same question on MathStack.

Comment: Can you please state your precise assumptions on $f$. Two small remarks right away: (1) It seems $f$ is defined on $(0,\infty)$ (not $\mathbb R$); (2) if $f\in L^1(0,\infty)$, then the integral is not guaranteed to converge at a given $x$.

Comment: Note that I_1(f) is an antiderivative of f, and that I_a (I_b(f))  =  I_(a+b)(f).

Answer (score 1):

Let $H=\mathbf 1_{\mathbb R^+}$ be the Heaviside function and let us define $g$ by
$
g(x)=H(x) x^{-1/2}.
$
We note that $g$ is homogeneous with degree $-1/2$ and thus its Fourier transform is homogeneous with degree $\frac12-1=-\frac12$. Moreover the function $F=Hf$ belongs to $L^1(\mathbb R)$ and you have assumed that
$$
F\ast g=0.
$$
Thanks to the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, the Fourier transform of a function in
$L^1(\mathbb R)$ is a (uniformly) continuous function (going to 0 at infinity). As a consequence we get that
$
\hat F \hat g=0.
$
Since we have
\begin{multline}\hat g(\xi)=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-2iπ s\text{ sign} \xi} s^{-1/2}ds\vert\xi\vert^{-1/2}
\\=\vert\xi\vert^{-1/2}\Bigl\{H(\xi)\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-2iπ s} s^{-1/2}ds
+
H(-\xi)\int_0^{+\infty}e^{2iπ s} s^{-1/2}ds\Bigr\},
\end{multline}
we obtain that the continuous function $\hat F$ is supported at the origin, thus is the zero function. As a consequence $F=0$.

Comment: Thank you! I do not understand why $\hat{F} \hat{g} = 0$. Isn't the Fourier transform of $0$ just $0$ concentrated at the origin?

Comment: I also don't understand why computing the Fourier transform of $g$ is useful (by the way, are you sure about the multiplication by $|\xi|^{-1/2}$?) and why it proves that $\hat{F}$ is supported at the origin.